# nginx server_name regex

Tags: nginx

server_name in nginx does not match

I want to match with such FQDNs
I came up with

```
server_name "~^(www.)?ucwebapi-uccore(\d{0,3})-(\d{0,3})\.testme\.net";
```

To Match

```
ucwebapi.testme.net
ucwebapi-uccore.testme.net
ucwebapi-uccore1-0.testme.net
ucwebapi-uccore999-999.testme.net
```

Validated with https://regex101.com/r/tAwEp9/2

Tested with

```
server_name "~^(www.)?ucwebapi-uccore(\d{0,3})-(\d{0,3})\.testme\.net ucwebapi1.testme.net";
```

to see if ucwebapi1.testme.de server is reachable at all.

Is there any restriction im not aware of?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
server_name "~^(www.)?ucwebapi(-uccore)?(\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})?\.testme\.net";
```

It looks like there are some missing characters between your regex101 page and what ended up in your config.

I've also tuned it a bit so that it will NOT match:

```
ucwebapi-uccore999.testme.net
ucwebapi-uccore-.testme.net
ucwebapi-uccore-999.testme.net
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen server_name configurations with double-quotes... but I'm not shure if that solves the problem.

Some example configurations [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms).

**Edit:** Do you have a default virtual server like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 404; # default
}

# now add your specific server
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name "~^(www.)?ucwebapi-uccore(\d{0,3})-(\d{0,3})\.testme\.net ucwebapi1.testme.net";
    ...
}
```

Specific configurations will only work if you have a default configured.

**@abcdn**: your absolutely right, i didn't know that!

Comment: Quote: "A regular expression containing the characters “{” and “}” should be quoted". src: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
server_name "~^(www.)?ucwebapi-uccore(\d{0,3})-(\d{0,3})\.testme\.net" ucwebapi1.testme.net;
```

Your `server_name` quotes encompassed the entire line. What is probably perceived as 2 separate entries, nginx interpolated as a single entry.